# No Route Matches error when using Sidekiq mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines, sidekiq

I am using a mountable engine (comes with Sidekiq) and am receiving the error `No route matches [GET] "/sidekiq"` for the URL `http://localhost:3000/sidekiq`. Here is the relevant code:

```
routes.rb:

NoveltyStats::Application.routes.draw do  
  require 'sidekiq/web'
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  ...
end
```

Here is the output from `rake routes`:

```
sidekiq_web        /sidekiq
....
```

Goes without saying that other routes within the application work just fine.

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? the same is happening to me

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I did resolve the problem but I don't know what I did. My file history got truncated when I had a corrupt GIT repository so I can't see back that far. The answer below may have some validity for you but I didn't have any constraints at the time (I do now).

Comment: We recently had this issue. I was pretty stumped, but it turned out to be an access issue. We only mount the sidekiq if the user has access (i.e. they are an admin). I know it's different from this issue, but it might help since we received the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using constraints to restrict access to sidekiq?

If so this can be caused when the constraints are not met.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Fixed it by upgrading sinatra gem to a version greater than 1.3